# PHP: call function in foreach, or outside?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a big function with `foreach`, that makes over 800 MySQL requests. 
It is Executed in 5-6 seconds. Call this function `F1`.

So like this:

```
function F1(){
foreach($current_id as $id){
request (SELECT * FROM wp_posts o LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_posts r ON 
o.post_parent = r.ID WHERE r.id = '$id' AND o.post_type = 'product')
request (update wp_postmeta
set meta_value = $val
where meta_key in ('_price','_regular_price') and post_id IN
(select tempP.tempId from(
select v.id as tempId from wp_posts v join wp_postmeta pm on (pm.post_id = 
v.id) join wp_posts p on (v.post_parent = p.id) where meta_key ='_price' and 
v.post_type = 'product_variation' and p.id = '$id') as tempP))
 request (UPDATE simple request very short)
}
}
```

I want to add one more function `F2` to send emails, so i need near 400 short MySQL requests to check in DataBASE ID of element in table, and if it exist, so send email to person.

Question is: where better to call F2 to send emails in F1 or outside?

VAR 1:

```
function F1(){
  foreach($current_id as $id){
   request (SELECT with INNER JOIN 0, 002 sec)
  request (UPDATE with inner JOIN near 0,04)
 request (UPDATE simple request very short)
   if($id is){
   so call function F2(){
     send email
   }
   } 
 }
}
```

VAR 2:

```
    function F1(){
      foreach($current_id as $id){
       request (SELECT with INNER JOIN 0, 002 sec)
       request (UPDATE with inner JOIN near 0,04)
        request (UPDATE simple request very short)
       if($id is){
         $array_ids = array_merge($id);
       } 
     }
    }
   if (!empty($array_ids)){
   explode;
   foreach ($find_id as id){
     so call function F2(){
         send email
       }
   }
}
```

Or is it better solution?

Comment: This is really hypothetical in its current form. Why not try both and find out?

Comment: Can you show what you're doing with the `mysql`, maybe there's a better approach?

Comment: Are the mails personalised?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, nesting F2 within F1 would execute 320,000 mysql queries... That doesn't seem like the best way to do it.

Comment: No mails are not personlised

Comment: @Alex Pain, Then do it outside and send just one e-mail with all the adresses in bcc

Comment: ... or even get all the emails with 1 query then iterate over the result set and send the emails. 800 queries sounds like an incorrect approach.

Comment: So i have no idea how to get SELECT and 2 different UPDATE requests in ONE request. I have 200-300 items and each must be select and update.

Comment: @Peter M  I think so better call it outside, like you said.

Comment: @Alex Pain, Could you provide an example of the select and update queries?

Comment: @Peter M Yes, look at this